# Memberships - Renewals and grace periods

Tags: civimember

I seem to remember doing this in the past, but can't recall how I did it.

We need a membership where:

- it's one price to join
- one price to renew during the grace
- one price to renew after the grace

Answer (score 3):

You could use the CiviDiscount module and tie various discounts to membership status rules.
You would need to create a discount code for each membership type and status and then in the "Automatic discounts" section at the bottom of the settings for the discount code, choose the appropriate membership status for that code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I think I remember what I did previously - folks were directed to a page that had blocks on it that were available based on your membership. So you could only get the renewal priced page if you were current or grace. The auto discounts may be a better way to go.